# USB Mouse and Keyboard stop working during system restoration

Tags: windows-7, usb, keyboard, mouse, system-restore

I'm trying to entirely wipe my PC using a Win7 installation disc and whenever I'm prompted to restart my PC to start the restore process my keyboard and mouse both die. I've tried just having my mouse plugged in and just having my keyboard plugged in each time I try to restart but they just cease to work. I have a GeForce keyboard and a Razer mouse if that helps.

Please all I want to do is restore my PC and its become such a pain. I've tried everything I know and tried googling fixes and nothing has worked thus far. I've even wanted to try in Safemode but either f8 isn't the button to spam or my PC just ignores me ahaha. Please help!

Comment: Both corded devices?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to go into your computer bios to change the Legacy bios mode, and enable it. Here is a very detailed guide thats easy to follow along to help you throu this process.
https://neosmart.net/wiki/enable-legacy-boot-mode/
I would try these options first and if they don't get you out the hole your in try with your local areas IT store, "Staples".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Win7 ISO installation package doesn't have drivers for EHCI/xHCI USB controllers. As soon as the intermediate Windows image takes control over PC, the BIOS/UEFI drivers are eliminated, the USB drops off, and you can't proceed with anything USB. To fix the issue you need to re-create the ISO boot image, for example, as suggested in [this article by Thomas Maurer](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2011/01/add-drivers-to-windows-installation-iso/). This [INTEL article](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000017241/mini-pcs.html) might be of help as well.